# What is a good blog system for use with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, blogs

I am designing a full featured website that includes a blog on the homepage. I want it to be full featured, but I dont want to spend forever coding it. Is there any good blogging system that can be easily integrated with CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly I would separate CodeIgniter from the blog code.  If you look at many websites that have a blog these days, they will often have the main application at www.example.com and then host their blog at blog.example.com, where they will have an installation of Wordpress (which I recommend, since you already have a php/mysql stack) or something similar.  You can still make this work if you'd prefer to have it at example.com/blog but depending on your site you may have to do some modification of things like your .htaccess file, as well as your blog system theme if you want it to look like the rest of your site.

Comment: I'm not sure that suggesting somebody uses WordPress for one element of their website while having to build a totally separate codebase for the rest of their site is really the best idea. There are plenty of existing blog solutions for CodeIgniter such as my project PyroCMS http://pyrocms.com and countless other solutions. No point building in roadblocks or re-inventing the wheel when simple solutions already exist.

Comment: @Phil can you give us a link that will solve specifically the blog problem? I would like to use your system but not the whole CMS

Comment: Well as I mentioned, it largely depends on what you want to do with the blog.  If I was building a new website for my startup and wanted to have an engineering or company blog, for example, I would much prefer to use a standalone solution that I did not have to create any code for.  If the blog functionality needed to integrate with other features of my site, then I would of course use a code igniter module as you suggest.

Comment: PyroCMS is a modular CMS with core modules and addons. If you don't want to have a gallery or whatever else then delete it. Core modules are things like users, themes, permissions, etc all of which you need for your site.

Answer (score 3):

[Expression Engine 2.0](http://expressionengine.com/) is built on CodeIgniter, and made by the same company Ellis Labs.  It's pretty decent, and will be very familiar to you if you're already familiar with CI.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on making a public blogging platform, you can not use Expression Engine due to licensing violation. see: http://expressionengine.com/sales_faq/article/myspace_blogservice/

For a free alternative, try http://pyrocms.com/ . I have been thinking about implementing myself as I wish to implement a blog on my current site.